# aapt.exe craches when I try to add a new Activity to my project or clean project

Tags: android, crash, aapt

I use standard settings when create a new BlankActivity to project. Because of this problem, I have new problems with android-support-v4.jar and appcompat_v7 in my project. There are some folders of appcompat_v7 are created in my workspace (appcompat_v7).

How can I solve this problem?

SDK tools 22.6.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has easy solution. After update ADT-plugin, there is new way for adding activities to project with fragment and framelayout, and class that extended from ActionBarActivity with support_v4 libraries.

It necessary to create a new project (it does not matter which API level) and replace old android-support-v4.jar libruary by a new version of this library from just created project (/libs/android-support-v4.jar).